# Rendering Finished ASP.net, VB.NET Loading GIF

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, rendering

I have been looking hard for a solution and can not seem to find anything.

Basically I have 50,000 rows in a database that is loading up rendering on the screen but takes about 20 seconds to load.

I was wondering if you can find out when asp has finished rendering, something like this;

```
Protected Sub Page Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    imgLoading.Visible = True
    lvBigPage.Visible = False

    Dim DE As New DE()
    lvBigPage.DataSource = DE.BigPage_Get()
    lvBigPage.DataBind()
End Sub

Private Sub lvBigPage_RenderingComplete(sender As Object, e As ListViewItemEventArgs) Handles lvBigPage.RenderingComplete
    imgLoading.Visible = false
    lvBigPage.Visible = True
End Sub
```

Using this I will be able to make some sort of load ajax gif until the page is loaded.

Comment: Could you load 100 records and the rest with ajax? The displaying and removing of the gif will have to be done client side (javascript).

Comment: I can't image a user that would like to look at 50,000 records.

Comment: Why would you want to determine when ASP is done fetching the records vs just waiting for the success AJAX reply?  You won't have data to display until the client has received the full response anyway.

Comment: OK, I only have about 3000 records of stock list. The SQL query takes 2 seconds and the rendering takes about 8 seconds, still the rendering takes a bit of time and I don't want users clicking on stuff whilst loading, hence the loading gif. There will be only one large gif in the center of the screen. I am using update panels in asp which obviously uses ajax, how do I hijack this to check if ajax is finished using javascript and perform the above operation that way.